# Xcode compactMap returning empty array with decodable

Tags: json, xcode, google-cloud-firestore

I encoded my IGNotification array into a dictionary and am trying to decode the array into data while performing a compactMap on IGNotification. I expect the data to be displayed on a tableView but instead the array is empty. Does anyone know why this is happening?

below is the getNotifications function that has the compact map along with my Decodable extension.

getNotifications function:

```
public func getNotifications(
    completion: @escaping ([IGNotification]) -> Void
) {
    guard let username = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "username") else {
        completion([])
        return
    }
    let ref = firestoreDatabase.collection("users").document(username).collection("notifications")
    ref.getDocuments { snapshot, error in
        guard let notifications = snapshot?.documents.compactMap({
            IGNotification(with: $0.data())
        }),
        error == nil else {
            completion([])
            return
        }

        completion(notifications)
        print(notifications)
    }
}
```

Decodable extension:

```
extension Decodable {
/// Create model with dictionary
/// - Parameter dictionary: Firestore data

init?(with dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    print("executed")
    guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(
        withJSONObject: dictionary,
        options: .prettyPrinted
    ) else {
        return nil
    }
    print("result")
    guard let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(
        Self.self,
        from: data
    ) else {
        return nil
    }
    self = result
    print("executed")
}
```

}

Comment: You ignore potential errors with `try?`, so you throw away a possible help. And – unrelated to the issue – delete the `.prettyPrinted` option. The decoder doesn't care.

Comment: @vadian I will remove the '.prettyPrinted', thank you. However, when I remove the try the error "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Data'" is thrown. I am having issues resolving this new error.

Comment: Replace `guard let` with a do - catch block and print the` error`.